# unable to change array size at runtime in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm kinda new in java and I'm trying to port my experience from c# world to java here is the code :

```
public class TestBasket {

    private Item[] shops  = {} ; 
    int arraysIndex=0;

    public static void main(String argc[]){


        TestBasket tb = new TestBasket();

        try{
        tb.storeItems(new Item("test", 100));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        }

    public void storeItems(Item it){

        if (arraysIndex >= shops.length){

            ///resizeArray(shops);
            System.out.println("the count of length is" + shops.length);
            cpArr(shops);
            System.out.println("the count of length is" + shops.length);

        }
        shops[arraysIndex] = it;
        arraysIndex++;


    }



    //this is a generic method to resize every kind of array 

    public Item[] cpArr(Item[] arr){
        Item[] retArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 10);
        return retArr;
    }
}
```

after executing the program I will get this message :

> length is0
>
> length is0
>
> Error
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

which means still the length of array is zero which it shouldn't be zero.
I'm confused where did I go wrong?

regards.

---

I get my answer it was my fault I have to get the retrun value as the result which I didn't do that.

Comment: Since you figured it out and it appears to have been trivial, please delete the question.

Comment: Or more appropriately, accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You're not using the result of:

```
cpArr(shops);
```

What this method does is create a NEW array, nothing changes in your current one! 
So you need to do:

```
shops = cpArr(shops);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember arrays in java have a fixed size and you have to copy the data in a new bigger array. To have lists of dynamic size I recommend using the [Array List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Example:

```
import java.util.*; //Really generic import
// You can use templates or the generic ArrayList which stores "Object" type
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add one item at a time
myArray.add("Hello");
// Add items from a Collection object
myArray.addAll(Arrays.toList(new String[]{"World", "Just", "Demo"});
// Get item
myArray.get(0);
// Remove item
myArray.remove(0);
```

I think you can guess the rest (and read the javadoc).
Hope I can be of help

**NB**: I havent done Java in a while but it should be mostly right.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set: `shop = cpArr(shops)` instead of just calling the method.